# Puppet 3 loop execution only if variable is defined within a template

Tags: ruby, templates, loops, erb, puppet

I am trying to create a loop only if `index` is defined. But it looks like 
erb can't handle a loop within a if clause.

```
<% if(@index) %>
index <% index_files.each do |i| %> <%= i %> <% end %>;
<% end %>
```

Expected Result was:
`index index.html index.php`
or
`""`

Syntax error i got:

My flat approach failed as expected:

```
<% if(@index_files) %> try_files <% end %>  <% index_files.each do |i| %> <%= i %> <% end %>
```

I defined `index_files` as `undef` => broke the each loop
I defined an empty array => since an empty array is defined it didn't work.

Maybe I can check the length of `index_files`?
Or do I need a complete different way to solve the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't entirely clear.  Could you re-edit this to make it precisely clear what the error message?  erb *can* handle a loop within an if block, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the same and it works for me, also for nginx ;).

For example:`<% if @proxy_ignore_headers %>    proxy_ignore_headers<% proxy_ignore_headers.each do |i| -%> <%= i %><% end -%>;`

That works like a charm, the only difference with you is using () for the if condition, but I bet puppet supports (). It's weird, maybe you had pressed a bad combination generating a character that can't be seen but it's messing with your code, try writing all from scratch just in case.

[You can see the full template here](https://github.com/guruHub/puppet-nginx/blob/guzmandev/templates/vhost/vhost_location_proxy.erb)

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

At first glance you just need to change

```
index_files.each
```

to

```
@index_files.each
```

Comment: No.  Are you familiar with puppet? The **@** is a test to see if the variable exists.

Comment: But this isn't Puppet ... in a Puppet catalog the templates are all erb. This is an erb template, the one place in Puppet where Ruby is used directly, and in fact there is no Puppet language syntax used at all in templates. They have the syntax of the file they are generating and pure Ruby for the control syntax

Comment: @itsbruce: In Puppet ERB templates, it *is* recommended to use `@` in front of variables to ensure you're not calling Ruby functions instead.